# Rspec mock ActiveRecord::Relation instead of class object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, ruby-grape

I want to mock one line from my endpoint:

```
InquiryProcessFilters::CompanyName.new(params[:filters][:company_name].downcase).call
```

So I've mock:

```
let(:company_name_filter_mock) { instance_double(InquiryProcessFilters::CompanyName) }

before do
  allow(InquiryProcessFilters::CompanyName).to(receive(:new).and_return(company_name_filter_mock))
  allow(company_name_filter_mock).to receive(:call).and_return(second_inquiry_process)
end
```

The problem is that my class from endpoint returns result as `ActiveRecord_Relation` and this is my desired result. How to update my mock to achieve that?

Comment: You mean that `second_inquiry_process` is an AR relation?

Comment: @mrzasa yes, it should be an AR relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options.

If you care about not touching DB in the spec and it's enough to get `Enumerable`, assign an array to `second_inquiry_process`, e.g.:

```
let(:second_inquiry_process) { [inquiry_process_instance] }
```

or with FactoryBot

```
let(:second_inquiry_process) { build_list :inquiry_process, 1 }
```

If you want to have full AR relation (and I suppose you do), create records in the db and assign them to the variable, e.g.:

```
let(:inquiry_process_instance) { create :inquiry_proces }
let(:second_inquiry_process) { InquiryProcess.where(id: inquiry_process_instance.id) }
```